# Powershell Select-Object like two value

Tags: powershell

first time posting here.
I'm stuck with what i thought would be a simple task, trying to list Computers in AD with one or another Membership.

I just want to look in my @Ring variable for two strings as such as '*UPGRADE*' or '*RING_*'
Is there a simple way to do this ?

Thanks,

For now my code is like that

```
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $Base_recherche -Properties * -Filter * |

Select-Object   @{name="Nom machine";expression={$_.Name}},
                @{n="Dernière date de connexion";e={$_.LastLogonDate}},
                @{n="Systeme exploitation";expression={$_.OperatingSystem}},
                @{n="Version";expression={$_.OperatingSystemVersion}},
                @{n="CheminAD";expression={$_.CanonicalName}},               
                @{n="Ring";e={$_.memberof -like '*UPGRADE*'}} |        
               
Export-CSV $Chemin_Export -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Should the resulting `Ring` property value be a true/false?

Answer (score 0):

It seems if you need to only choose AD objects with a membership of '*UPGRADE*' or '*RING_*' you will need to use the -Filter parameter to filter out the objects ahead of time.

```
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $Base_recherche -Properties * -Filter 'memberof -like '*UPGRADE*' -or memberof -like '*RING_*'
```

This will give you just the objects that satisfy the condition.

EDIT

You can combine the above code with your Select-Object but just add both elements you are looking for.

```
@{name="Ring";expression={$_.memberof -like '*Ring_*'}},
@{name="Upgrade";expression={$_.memberof -like '*UPGRADE*'}}
```

This will give you the two columns in your CSV with TRUE/FALSE values per computer line. This way you can know which systems belong to corresponding groups.

```
ComputerName,Ring,UPGRADE
machineA,true,false
machineb,true,true
machinec,false,true
```

Answer (score 0):

`Get-ADComputer` by default returns objects with these properties:
DistinguishedName, DNSHostName, Enabled, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID,  UserPrincipalName

By writing `-Properties *` you're asking for ALL properties, which is wasteful and time consuming.
Better ask for the extra properties you DO need

Below joins the MemberOf DN's that have either 'UPGRADE' or 'RING_' with a semi-colon as `Ring` property in the output

```
$properties = 'LastLogonDate', 'OperatingSystem', 'OperatingSystemVersion', 'CanonicalName', 'MemberOf'
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $Base_recherche -Properties $properties -Filter * |
Select-Object @{Name = "Nom machine"; Expression = {$_.Name}},
              @{Name = "Dernière date de connexion"; Expression = {$_.LastLogonDate}},
              @{Name = "Systeme exploitation"; Expression = {$_.OperatingSystem}},
              @{Name = "Version"; Expression = {$_.OperatingSystemVersion}},
              @{Name = "CheminAD"; Expression = {$_.CanonicalName}},
              @{Name = "Ring"; Expression = {($_.MemberOf -match 'UPGRADE|RING_') -join '; '}} |        
           
Export-CSV -Path $Chemin_Export -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want your `Ring` property to be just True if there is any MemberOf that has either 'UPGRADE' or 'RING_' found or False otherwise, then change this

```
@{Name = "Ring"; Expression = {($_.MemberOf -match 'UPGRADE|RING_') -join '; '}}
```

into

```
@{Name = "Ring"; Expression = {[bool]($_.MemberOf -match 'UPGRADE|RING_')}}
```